# Grouping multiple values

Tags: crystal-reports

Grouping multiple values on Details section

I have got an output from SQL query:

ID  Value

```
1     1
1     3
1     5
1     7
1     9
2     1
2     4
3     1
3     2
3     3
```

I just want to have on each page  ID and whole list of values assigned to this id. On next page I should have next ID a it's values.
As you can see for ID 1 I have got 4 values, for 2 I have got only 2 values, for 3 I have got 3 values. I want to say that how many values I have got for particular ID can be different.

I don't know what is the name of this kind go grouping, If someone will name it I will be able to dig the Internet to find the solution.
If someone knew how to do this and will share the knowledge I will really appreciate this.

Best regards,
Volcano

Answer (score 1):

You should add a group (`Insert Group`) for `ID` and put `Value` in the detail section. Make sure to start each group on a new page (`Section Expert` for your group header or footer, then tick `New Page Before / After`.